# joining 2 data frames with dates to expand to each unit

Tags: r, dataframe, date, join, merge

I have dataframe1 such as:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'),as.Date('2020-09-20'),by = 1)
newdf <- data.frame(dates)
```

and I have dataframe2 such as:

```
unit     Date         total_appoints  region   category
1       2019-01-03          3          south     high
1       2019-05-15          4          south     high
1       2020-02-02          2          south     high
2       2019-04-04          1          north     low
2       2020-03-02          0          north     low
```

how can I join dataframe1 into dataframe2 where I have all dates associated to each unit with 0 in case the date is not the dataframe2 such as:

```
unit     Date         total_appoints
1       2019-01-01          0
1       2019-01-02          0
1       2019-01-03          3
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ben - as mentioned below, dataframe1 does not have unit to match dataframe2, only dates. any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarification. It sounds like you want all dates from data frame 1 for all units. In that case, `complete` from `tidyr` might be helpful here.

**Edit**: You can use `fill` to change `NA` for `region` and `category` within the same `unit` as already grouped by `unit`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataframe2 %>%
  group_by(unit) %>%
  complete(unit, 
           Date = newdf$dates, 
           fill = list(total_appoints = 0)) %>%
  fill(region, category, .direction = "updown")
```

**Output**

```
    unit Date       total_appoints region category
   <dbl> <date>              <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   
 1     1 2019-01-01              0 south  high    
 2     1 2019-01-02              0 south  high    
 3     1 2019-01-03              3 south  high    
 4     1 2019-01-04              0 south  high    
 5     1 2019-01-05              0 south  high
 ...
```

Comment: thanks very much Ben. dataframe1 does not have 'unit' to match with dataframe2. dataframe1 only has the dates I created.. that's why I don't know how to do this! Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you want all dates for all units, so that unit 1 will have dates from 1/1/19-9/20/20 and unit 2 will have dates from 1/1/19-9/20/20, etc. Is that correct? See my edited answer using `tidyverse` and let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot Ben - this works! I just forgot to say that my dataframe2 has 2 other columns (edited above) which get NAs when I run your code - any thoughts on how to maintain this info for the 'unit' ?

Comment: Yes, you can also include `fill` in your pipe at the end. This will convert the `NA` to the correct `region` and `category` shared within the same `unit` (already grouped by `unit`). Please see edited answer.